# I want to delete part of a string using strcpy

Tags: c, string

For example i have the the following

strings: `"Home=London","Country=England","User=John"`

i want to look at these string and keep only what is to the left of `'='` using strcpy.

Comment: You can't do that with `strcpy()`. It always copies to the end of the string.

Comment: Just replace `'='` with `'\0'`

Comment: Do you want to do this in place or with a copy? You could get the position of `=` and then use `strncpy()` to only copy that much. Then you have to remember to add the null terminator.

Comment: Use `strchr` to find where (and if) the `'='` is. Note that you can't overwrite a string literal.

Comment: Assumeing these strings are in writable memory (i.e.) `char strings[30][] = { Home=London","Country=England","User=John" };` and _not_ `char **strings = { Home=London","Country=England","User=John" };`, you can do (e.g): `char *cp = strchr(strings[i],'='); if (cp != NULL) *cp = 0;` (looping on `i`).

Comment: @MagicThanos probably because it is a very weird and specific question with no code and no explanation given (likely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) and therefore unlikely to be useful to anyone else other than OP.

Answer (score 2):

The [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function cannot do this. It will operate on the entire string upto the null terminator. However, [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) does take an argument indicating how many characters to copy.

Then we just need to use [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to find a pointer to the first occurrence of `'='` and do some pointer arithmetic to find the offset in characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "hello=world";
    char s2[strlen(s1)+1];
 
    char *equals_sign = strchr(s1, '=');
 
    if (!equals_sign) {
        printf("No equals sign found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t offset = equals_sign - s1;

    strncpy(s2, s1, offset);
    s2[offset] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", s2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
hello
```

Note that this is creating a new string rather than in-place modifying the existing string. Because strings are null-terminated (nothing after the null terminator is considered when using standard string functions) we don't need to "erase" the unwanted parts of a string, just insert a null terminator. The likes of `strcpy` and `strncpy` are completely unnecessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "hello=world";
 
    char *equals_sign = strchr(s1, '=');
 
    if (!equals_sign) {
        printf("No equals sign found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    *equals_sign = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", s1);
    
    return 0;
}
```